# Finding a basis for {$f\in $ Span{$e^{x}, e^{2x}, e^{3x}$} | $f(0) = f'(0) = 0$}

Tags: linear-algebra

How do you find a basis for {$f\in $ Span{$e^{x}, e^{2x}, e^{3x}$} | $f(0) = f'(0) = 0$}?

So the set {$e^{x}, e^{2x}, e^{3x}$} is linearly independent. From the requirement that $f(0) = 0$ we get the equation $a1 + a2 + a3 = 0$ and from $f'(0) = 0$ we get the equation  $a1 + 2a2 + 3a3 = 0$.

That is just what I thought, but when I went through the question that way, I didn't get the right answer.

Comment: What did you get, and why do you think it isn't the right answer? Note that there could be multiple right answers to a question of this type...

Comment: oh geeze thanks to whoever edited it. The reason I messed up is because I foolishly integrated instead of taking the derivative in the second equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe if
\begin{align}
f(x) = c_1 e^x+c_2e^{2x}+c_3e^{3x}
\end{align}
then
\begin{align}
f'(x) = c_1e^x + 2c_2e^{2x}+3c_3e^{3x}.
\end{align}
Hence we have the two equation
\begin{align}
&c_1+c_2+c_3=0\\
&c_1+2c_2+3c_3=0
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
c_2+2c_3 = 0 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ c_2 = -2c_3 \ \ \text{ and } \ \ c_1= c_3.
\end{align}
Thus, we have
\begin{align}
f(x) = c e^x-2ce^{2x}+ce^{3x} = c(e^x-2e^{2x}+e^{3x}).
\end{align}

Hence $\{f \in \operatorname{Span}\{e^x, e^{2x}, e^{3x}\} \mid f(0) = f'(0) = 0\} = \operatorname{Span}\{e^x-2e^{2x}+e^{3x}\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Write

$$f(x)=ae^x+be^{2x}+ce^{3x}\implies\begin{cases}I\;\;0=f(0)=a+b+c\\{}\\II\;\,0=f'(0)=a+2b+3c\end{cases}$$

Solve the resulting linear system , for example substracting I from II:

$$b+2c=0\implies b=-2c\stackrel{I}\implies a-2c+c=0\implies a=c$$

and thus any function of the form

$$f(x)=a\left(e^x-2e^{2x}+e^{3x}\right)$$

will do work.

Answer (score 0):

we have
$a_1+a_2+a_3=0$ and

$a_1+2a_2+3a_3=0$.

by substraction we get

$a_2=-2a_3$  and  replacing in the first

equation gives $a_1=a_3$.

finally $f(x)$ will be of the form

$a_3(e^x-2e^{2x}+e^{3x})$

so the only vector of the basis is

$e^x-2e^{2x}+e^{3x}$.